# How to cycle className over children in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I would like to use a `setInterval` to cycle which `<li>` object has a `className` of "showing", like this [simple slideshow](https://codepen.io/SitePoint/pen/KzjpGj). I don't know how to do this in React-land.

```
function NumberList() {
  const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
  return (
    <ul>
      {
        numbers.map((number) =>
          <li key={number.toString()}>{number}</li>
        )
      }
    </ul>
  );
}


ReactDOM.render(
  <NumberList />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

Anybody have any ideas?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's a working demo. Basically, you need to start a timer and keep the current showing list item in the state. The timer will increment the current number every 500ms and wrap around when it exceeds the number of items.

Some things to take note of:

1. Use the alternative signature of `this.setState` because `setState` is not guaranteed to be synchronous and if you refer to `this.state` within `setState` it might be outdated.
2. Remember to clear the timer upon unmount of the component.

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
    this.state = {
      current: 0,
    };
  }

  componentDidMount() {
    this.timerId = setInterval(() => {
      this.setState(state => ({
        ...state,
        current: (state.current + 1) % this.numbers.length,
      }));
    }, 500);
  }

  componentWillUnmount() {
    clearInterval(this.timerId);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <ul>
          {this.numbers.map((number, index) => (
            <li
              key={number}
              className={index === this.state.current ? 'slide showing' : 'slide'}
            >
              {number}
            </li>
          ))}
        </ul>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />,
  document.getElementById('root')
);
```

```css
.slide {
 font-size: 40px;
 padding: 40px;
 box-sizing: border-box;
 background: #333;
 color: #fff;
  display: none;
  width: 100%;
  height: 40px;
}

.slide.showing {
  display: inherit;
}

.slide:nth-of-type(1){
 background: red;
}
.slide:nth-of-type(2){
 background: orange;
}
.slide:nth-of-type(3){
 background: green;
}
.slide:nth-of-type(4){
 background: blue;
}
.slide:nth-of-type(5){
 background: purple;
}
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>

<div id="root"><div>
```

Comment: I really like your use of `current: (state.current + 1) % 5`. Definitely going to keep that in mind in the future. But wouldn't it be better to use `state.current.length` instead of `5` though?

Comment: `state.current` is a number, it's not an array. If OP wants to keep the numbers within the list component, there's no way for the parent component to know how many list items there are. If the numbers are shifted out into the parent component into a `numbers` property of `this.state`, then it's possible to do: `current: (state.current + 1) % state.numbers.length`

Comment: Oh, didn't pay close enough attention for some reason. Thanks for the explanation.

Comment: This is great! I think it best to manage the slides with their `index` rather than the array value since I'll be needing to make a slideshow with data other than numbers 1 through 5. Thanks for the heads up on the `setState`. The modulus use here is very clever. I need multiple instances of these slideshows and I won't need them to interact with anything else, so I don't see a reason to manage the state outside of the component. Is there a reason I should manage the state in a parent of the component? My modified version of the [simple slideshow](https://codepen.io/danohlsen/pen/EovGEe).

Comment: Because functional components can't have states. I can merge that functional component into the parent if you prefer.

Comment: Right, it doesn't have to be a functional component, it can be a pure component, it doesn't matter to me. I'll mark this as the answer if you use the array index rather than the array value to manage the slide classes like I did in the codepen in my comment above.

Comment: I have merged it into one component and used the index. Also, since the `numbers` is part of the component now, there's no need to hardcode 5. Note that if `numbers` will change, make it part of `state`.

Answer (score 0):

You will probably need to use [`componentDidMount`](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#componentdidmount) function to use the `setInterval` function so you have access to the classes. Also use `ref` to get the hold of the element itself.

https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#when-to-use-refs

Within the `componentDidMount` get access to the element and then you should be able to any JS stuff.

demo: https://codesandbox.io/s/oopj96pv65

```
import React from "react";
import { render } from "react-dom";
import Hello from "./Hello";
import "./style.css";

class App extends React.Component {
  componentDidMount() {
    var slides = this.elem.children;
    var currentSlide = 0;

    setInterval(() => {
      slides[currentSlide].classList.remove("showing");
      currentSlide = (currentSlide + 1) % slides.length;
      slides[currentSlide].classList.add("showing");
    }, 2000);
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <ul
        id="slides"
        ref={elem => {
          this.elem = elem;
        }}
      >
        <li className="slide showing">Slide 1</li>
        <li className="slide">Slide 2</li>
        <li className="slide">Slide 3</li>
        <li className="slide">Slide 4</li>
        <li className="slide">Slide 5</li>
      </ul>
    );
  }
}

render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Comment: It's better to put the current showing slide as part of the React component's state and let it handle the DOM rendering instead. By directly accessing the DOM, you may mess up the rendering.

Comment: Not directly accessing the DOM. Using `refs` which are a part of react api. Having said that, maybe using `state` might be better option.

Comment: Refs give you direct access to the DOM node. From the link in your answer https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#when-to-use-refs - 
`For example, this code uses the ref callback to store a reference to a DOM node`

Answer (score 0):

Building on your simple example:

```
// Store the state outside of the components
const numbers = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5];
let activeNumber = 0;

// A stateless NumberList component takes the numbers and activeNumber props
function NumberList(props) {
    // The `active` class is conditionally added to the appropriate `li`
    return (
        <ul>
            {
                props.numbers.map((number) =>
                    <li key={number} className={props.activeNumber === number ? 'active' : ''}>
                        {number}
                    </li>
                )
            }
        </ul>
    );
}

// Render method takes in the active number
function render(activeNumber) {
    ReactDOM.render(
        <NumberList numbers={numbers} activeNumber={activeNumber} />,
        document.getElementById('root')
    );
}

// We set an interval timer to update activeNumber and re-render
setInterval(function() {
    if (activeNumber < numbers.length) {
        activeNumber++
    } else {
        activeNumber = 1;
    }
    render(activeNumber);
}, 1000);

render(); // Initial render
```