# How to use refs in React Higher-Order Component (HOC)

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ref

I have 3 nav items that have different markup but all need the same functionality -- to animate the `svg` `paths` within it in sequence. Sounds like a good scenario to use an HOC. However, I am unable to push the refs to an array via a `function` (activePaths) called from the ref in the WrappedComponent. I get an error `TypeError: _this2.activePaths is not a function`. Here's a working [codepen](https://codepen.io/danohlsen/pen/wpjwwN) of what I'm trying to accomplish for a single nav item without the using the HOC.

This is the code with the HOC that gives me the error.

```
export const withNavItem = WrappedComponent => class extends Component {
  constructor() {
    super();
    this.activePaths = this.activePaths.bind(this);
    this.markerPaths = [];
    this.rendered = false;
  }
  componentDidMount() {
    this.rendered = true;
    this.animatePaths();
  }

  animatePaths() {
    const { markerPaths } = this;
    // prepare stroke to be animated
    for (let i = 0; i < markerPaths.length; i++) {
      const path = markerPaths[i];
      const length = path.getTotalLength();
      path.setAttribute('strokeDasharray', length);
      path.style.strokeDashoffset = length;
    }
    // animate stroke
    const markerDrawing = anime({
      targets: markerPaths,
      strokeDashoffset: [anime.setDashoffset, 0],
      easing: 'easeInOutSine',
      duration: 400,
      delay(el, i) { return i * 150; },
      direction: 'alternate',
      loop: false,
    });
  }

  activePaths(el, linkType) {
    if (el === null || this.rendered) {
      return;
    }
    this.markerPaths.push(el);
  }

  render() {
    this.rendered = true;
    return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} />;
  }
};

export default withNavItem;




class NavItemHey extends React.Component {     
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span className="letter-holder">
          <span className="letter">H</span>
          <span className="letter-strokes letter-strokes--h">
            <span className="h-left-stroke letter-stroke">
              <svg className="letter-stroke__svg" viewBox="0 0 106 306">
                <path ref={el => this.activePaths(el)} className="letter-stroke__svg-path" d="M59,0c0,0,0.1,114-0.5,195.8S58,314.5,58,314.5" />
              </svg>
            </span>
            <span className="h-middle-stroke letter-stroke">
              <svg className="letter-stroke__svg" viewBox="0 0 118 106">
                <path ref={el => this.activePaths(el)} className="letter-stroke__svg-path" d="M0.1,58c0,0,33.5-0.1,66.8,0.5s63.2,0.5,63.2,0.5" />
              </svg>
            </span>
            <span className="h-right-stroke letter-stroke">
              <svg className="letter-stroke__svg" viewBox="0 0 109 304">
                <path ref={el => this.activePaths(el)} className="letter-stroke__svg-path" d="M59,0c0,0,0.1,114-0.5,195.8S58,314.5,58,314.5" />
              </svg>
            </span>
          </span>
        </span>

        <span className="letter-holder letter-e">
          <span className="letter">E</span>
          <span className="letter-strokes letter-strokes--e">
            <span className="e-left-stroke letter-stroke">
              <svg className="letter-stroke__svg" viewBox="0 0 106 316">
                <path ref={el => this.activePaths(el)} className="letter-stroke__svg-path" d="M59,0c0,0,0.1,114-0.5,195.8S58,314.5,58,314.5" />
              </svg>
            </span>
            <span className="e-top-stroke letter-stroke">
              <svg className="letter-stroke__svg" viewBox="0 0 134 105">
                <path ref={el => this.activePaths(el)} className="letter-stroke__svg-path" d="M0.2,51c0,0,24.5-0.1,57.8,0.5s75.2,0.5,75.2,0.5" />
              </svg>
            </span>
            <span className="e-middle-stroke letter-stroke">
              <svg className="letter-stroke__svg" viewBox="0 0 127 103">
                <path ref={el => this.activePaths(el)} className="letter-stroke__svg-path" d="M0.2,51c0,0,24.5-0.1,57.8,0.5s75.2,0.5,75.2,0.5" />
              </svg>
            </span>
            <span className="e-bottom-stroke letter-stroke">
              <svg className="letter-stroke__svg" viewBox="0 0 136 106">
                <path ref={el => this.activePaths(el)} className="letter-stroke__svg-path" d="M0.2,51c0,0,24.5-0.1,57.8,0.5s75.2,0.5,75.2,0.5" />
              </svg>
            </span>
          </span>
        </span>

        <span className="letter-holder letter-y">
          <span className="letter">Y</span>
          <span className="letter-strokes letter-strokes--y">
            <span className="y-left-stroke letter-stroke">
              <svg className="letter-stroke__svg" viewBox="0 0 196 232">
                <path ref={el => this.activePaths(el)} className="letter-stroke__svg-path" d="M58,0c0,42,13.8,71.5,37,117c24,47,52,80,52,116" />
              </svg>
            </span>
            <span className="y-right-stroke letter-stroke">
              <svg className="letter-stroke__svg" viewBox="0 0 218 215">
                <path ref={el => this.activePaths(el)} className="letter-stroke__svg-path" d="M110.5,0.1c0,0,0.1,83.6-0.5,143.5c-0.5,60-0.5,90-0.5,90" />
              </svg>
            </span>
            <span className="y-bottom-stroke letter-stroke">
              <svg className="letter-stroke__svg" viewBox="0 0 106 122">
                <path ref={el => this.activePaths(el)} className="letter-stroke__svg-path" d="M59,0.1c0,0,0.1,43.5-0.5,76.8S58,125.6,58,125.6" />
              </svg>
            </span>
          </span>
        </span>
      </div>
    );
  }
};

export default withNavItem(NavItemHeyo);
```

This [codepen](https://codepen.io/alaingalvan/pen/rrZXYB) is an example of someone taking a different route to animate some paths in sequence, though I'm unsure if I can replicate this since my paths are so nested.

Does anyone have any ideas?

Comment: It would really be good if you gave a simplified code example to solve this.

Comment: @Ska Does [this codepen](https://codepen.io/danohlsen/pen/movmLJ?editors=0010) help? Open up your console to see the array of elements logged by hocFunc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Error shows because **this** in child component represents child component and not HOC. To be able to use such function it needs to be passed by props to the child component. Some pseudo code:

```
// HOC
...
render() {
  this.rendered = true;
  return <WrappedComponent {...this.props} activePaths={this.activePaths} />;
} 

// WRAPPED COMPONENT
...
<path ref={el => this.props.activePaths(el)} />
```

Comment: Great! Thank you. Also the `this` inside the `activePaths` function seems to refer to the WrappedComponent, not the HOC, so in this case the array of refs `markerPaths` is undefined. Passing along the `markerPaths` array makes it work. `return <ComposedComponent {...this.props} activePaths={this.activePaths} markerPaths={this.markerPaths} />;`

Comment: u can also bind this function to current component by using this.props.activePaths.bind(this)

Comment: Oh nice, I didn't know that. Thanks for helping out a React newbie.

Answer (score 0):

If I understood correctly and from your codepen, I would simply add componentDidMount in your HOC and manipulate the refs there.

```
   const withNavItem = InnerComponent => class extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.elementsArray = [];
      }

// Added code
      componentDidMount(){
        this.elementsArray.forEach(el => {
          // change appearance, animate, etc...
          el.style.background = 'black'
        })
      }
// ^ added code    
      hocFunc(el, rendered) {
        if (el === null || rendered) { // don't keep adding in refs after rendered first time
          return;
        }
        this.elementsArray.push(el);
        console.log(this.elementsArray);
      }

      render() {
        return <InnerComponent {...this.props} elementsArray={this.elementsArray} hocFunc={this.hocFunc}  />;
      }
    };



    class NavItemOne extends React.Component {
      constructor() {
        super();
        this.rendered = false;
      }

      componentDidMount() {
        this.rendered = true;
      }

      render() {
        return (
          <div>
            <div ref={el => this.props.hocFunc(el, this.rendered)} className="box a" />
            <div ref={el => this.props.hocFunc(el, this.rendered)} className="box b" />
            <div ref={el => this.props.hocFunc(el, this.rendered)} className="box c" />
            <div ref={el => this.props.hocFunc(el, this.rendered)} className="box d" />
          </div>
        );
      }
    };

    const NavItemOneWrapped = withNavItem(NavItemOne);

    ReactDOM.render(
      <NavItemOneWrapped />,
      document.getElementById('root')
    );
```

Comment: That works. I would just make sure you actually need to use refs. I'm only using refs here because I'm doing some JS animation. Check out the React docs on [When to Use Refs](https://reactjs.org/docs/refs-and-the-dom.html#when-to-use-refs). For example, [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48088360/1496950) on how to build a simple slideshow in React needlessly uses refs, and [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/48088477/1496950) does it the preferred "declarative" way.